Facing issue while sending nested JSON logs in Sentinel
I am sending some custom JSON formatted logs using Sentinel HTTP Data Collector API. It is expanding the nested json into multiple columns like below.
additionalEventData_AuthenticationMethod_s
additionalEventData_CipherSuite_s
additionalEventData_MobileVersion_s
additionalEventData_SignatureVersion_s
additionalEventData_bytesTransferredIn_d
additionalEventData_bytesTransferredOut_d

Example JSON
{
"responseElements":null,
"additionalEventData": {
"SignatureVersion":"xxxx",
"CipherSuite":"xxxxxx",
"bytesTransferredIn":0,
"AuthenticationMethod":"xxxx",
"bytesTransferredOut":5
},
"managementEvent":true
}

However, I want to ingest the logs like below image. Where I can expand the logs by clicking the expand button.

I have tried to play with ConvertTo-Json -Depth operator while converting the logs to json. But its not working.
